# GUI quick fixes

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to make a simple login GUI in Javascript in Unity. I've currently got a simple GUI from the code below but i've been trying for a while to do some extra things:

- Make the password field show as asterisks (*) when something is typed in there.
- Change the login window from 'GUILayout.Window' to 'GUILayout.Box', i'm trying to remove the title bar from the window box so i'm trying to change it to a box but it won't work when I change the other variables too.
- Change the width of the 3 buttons at the bottom, so that they are the same width as the fields (80) and aligned to the right of the box (below the fields)

Thanks for your help :D

```
#pragma strict

var newSkin : GUISkin;
var logoTexture : Texture2D;
var aTexture : Texture;

private var username : String = ""; // String content would be shown as placeholder text
private var password : String = ""; // String content would be shown as placeholder text
private var submitted : boolean = false;

private var windowRect0 : Rect;

function Start()
{
}

function OnGUI() // Load GUI skin GUI.skin = newSkin;
{ 

    var screenWidth = Screen.width;
    var screenHeight = Screen.height;

    var windowWidth = 300;
    var windowHeight = 180;
    var windowX = ( 50 );
    var windowY = ( 50 );

    GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), "" ); // Box around the menu to display the background image

    // Postion the login window
    windowRect0 = Rect( windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight );

    // Display the login window for the user form below
    GUILayout.Window( 0, windowRect0, UserForm, "" );
}

function UserForm()
{
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();

    // Username Field
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.Label("Username ", GUILayout.Width(80));
    username = GUILayout.TextField( username );
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    // Password Field
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.Label("Password ", GUILayout.Width(80));
    password = GUILayout.TextField( password );
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    if ( GUILayout.Button( "Login" ) ) // Login button
    {
        submitted = true;
    }
    if ( GUILayout.Button( "Reset Password" ) ) // Reset password
    {
        username = "Username ";
        password = "Password ";
        submitted = false;
    }
    if ( GUILayout.Button( "Support" ) ) // Support button
    {
        // Enter action here when the "Support" button is pressed
    }

    if ( submitted )
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Submitted!");
    }

    GUILayout.EndVertical();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar project a while ago and I used the GUI.passwordfield 
(https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.PasswordField.html)
This sets the input to asterixes.
I don't really know what you mean with the second question, but the third:
You can easily assign lay-out information to your elements like in this example:

```
}
    if (GUI.Button(Rect(10,70,50,30),"Click"))
        Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");
}
```

Important here is this bit (10,70,50,30) this means the button is 10px from the left, 70 px from the top, 50px, wide and 30px tall.
You can use this on almost every element.

see http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.html for more info.